# Single if for 3 user choices? (I'm newbie)

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

I'm total beginner. I have made my program working but code looks really bad and I want to do something with an if statement so I will avoid copy-pasting it over and over again. I don't know functions yet (it can be done using one?), only loops, ifs and tables.

Here's the code:

```
print("What do you want to do?\n1)Give me just service name\n2)generate a link with service name\n3)do something else")
czynnosc = input()
if czynnosc == "1":
print("which unit id?" )
unitid = input()
unitid = int(unitid)
service = ""
if unitid >= 100 and unitid < 10000:
    service= "OneOne"
elif unitid >= 10000 and unitid < 30000:
    service= "Awesome20k+"
elif unitid >= 30000 and unitid < 40000: 
    service= "Great30k+"
elif unitid>= 40000 and unitid < 50000:
    service= "Asom40k+"
elif unitid>= 50000 and unitid < 60000:
    service= "Amazin50k+"
elif unitid>= 70000:
    service= "new"
else:
    print("Please validate unit id.")
print(f"Service name is {service}")
```

I want to use the same if statement for to generate service name from unitid for option 2 and 3, without copying and paste whole if statement again...

Is this possible? How?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Put code you can and want to use several times in a separate funcion. Here put your `if ... elif ... else` into a separate function (or possibly also more):

```
def get_service_by_unitid(unitid):
    service = ""
    if unitid >= 100 and unitid < 10000:
        service= "OneOne"
    elif unitid >= 10000 and unitid < 30000:
        service= "Awesome20k+"
    elif unitid >= 30000 and unitid < 40000: 
        service= "Great30k+"
    elif unitid>= 40000 and unitid < 50000:
        service= "Asom40k+"
    elif unitid>= 50000 and unitid < 60000:
        service= "Amazin50k+"
    elif unitid>= 70000:
        service= "new"
    else:
        print("Please validate unit id.")
    return service

print("What do you want to do?\n1)Give me just service name\n2)generate a link with service name\n3)do something else")
czynnosc = input()
if czynnosc == "1":
    print("which unit id?" )
    unitid = input()
    unitid = int(unitid)
    service = get_service_by_unitid(unitid)
    print(f"Service name is {service}")
elif czynnosc == "2":
    print("Which cost id?")
    costid = input()
    costid = int(costid)
    cost = get_service_by_unitid(costid)
    print(f"Cost name is {cost}")
```

Comment: If you find an answer useful, consider an upvote and in reply to your own questions accept the answer.